# C++ API implementation in heade file LNK2019

Tags: c++, header, lnk2019

I've 3 projects in my solution:
`Project_I`, `Project_A`, `Project_B`

Project_I contains header files only (no `cpp`), this projects defines interfaces in the header files that `Project_A` and `Projects_B` derive from and implement.

Since I want default behavior in `Project_I` interfaces methods to throw `NOT_IMPLEMENTED_EXCEPTION (my std::exception subtype)`, for each method declared in any of `Project_I` interfaces (header files) I wrote the this implementation in the header files, Also I implemented the C'TORs in the header files.

Now, when I try to compile the solution (after defining the project dependencies and etc...) I get the following error

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl Project_I::ClassA::ClassA()" referenced in function "public: __cdecl Project_B::ClassA_1::ClassA_1 K:\src\Project_B\ClassA_1.obj
```

Why does the VC++ compiler looks for the `.obj` file of `ClassA` in `project_I` (which needs to be built afterward) if there is no `cpp` file at all (the whole implementation is in the header file)?

Comment: Have you declared your class in Project_I as a __declspec(dllexport)?

Comment: Still better... paste declaration and definition of Project_I::ClassA, please.

Comment: Yes, Project_I declared as __declspec(dllexport) because all the projects compile to dlls.

Here is Project_I classA declaration & definition header (no cpp file):
<code>

namespace project_i
{

 //!  Histogram class.
 /*!
  Image histogram calculator interface class
 */
 class PROJECT_I_API ClassA
 {
 public:

virtual void Do_Something()
  {
   THROW_ERROR(IPM_NOT_SUPPORTED, "Operation is not implemented.");
  } 




  /*!
  Default C'TOR
  */
  ClassA(int& _num) : m_num(_num) {}



  /*!
  Virtual D'TOR of the object
  */
  virtual ~ClassA(){}

 protected:
  int& m_num;

 
 };



}

</code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Project_I::ClassA` is implemented into a header file, it will not be compiled at all into the dll (unless the header is included by some cpp file of Project_I, of course).

So, you have two options: create a cpp file and include the header containing `ClassA` definition or remove any `__declspec` declaration from it.

Comment: Thank you.
After adding cpp file and including the header file the problem solved